# Mixed sensitivity controller design

Tags: signal, control, control-system

I am defining a controller using the mixed sensitivity approach, and I have the following specifications:

- a low frequency attenuation of 60 dB
- a maximum resonance peak of 2

and I have chosen to use a weight on the sensitivity function and on the control sensitivity function. My code is the following:

```
s = tf('s');
G = 10/((s+10)*(s-1));
K1 = 10*(s+1)/s;
W_bt1 = 0.5;
W_bs1 = 0.25; %same cross over frequency as the previous point
M = 2;           %peak of the sensitivity
A = 0.001;      %attenuation
Ws1 = (s/M + W_bs1)/(s+W_bs1*A);   %sensitivity weight
Wt1 = (s/M + W_bt1)/(s+W_bt1*A);   %control sensitivity weight
%bodemag(1/Ws),grid;
[K2,CL,GAM1] = mixsyn(G,Ws1,[],Wt1);  %define the controller with the mixed 
sensitivity
display(GAM1);
K2 = minreal(K2);  %define a minimal order controller
```

the problem is that I have a frequency response which is:

[image]

and I don' t think it is a good frequency response since it is not a smooth response. So I think the problem is given by how I have chosen the weight for the control sensitivity. In fact, by using the A I have chosen, I obtain a low frequency attenuation of 60 dB as desired, but I am not sure I have to use it also for the control sensitivity weight.

Can somebody please help me?

[EDIT] I didn't mention in my question that I have a pole in the RHP, so this should also influence the frequency response of the system, in the sense that it imposes a lower limitation in for the bandwidth.

Comment: Why not define the transfer function properly?  Passband , Ripple in PB, Bandstop, attenuation of bandstops.

Comment: It's not clear what the bode diagram is, is this the closed loop response or the plant or the controller?

Comment: That is a plot of \$K_2\$ a controller that he got from "mixsyn" and the frequency weights \$W_{s1}\$ and \$W_{t1}\$.

Comment: Try to increase the sampling frequency, sometimes it could be the root of this problem.

Comment: The lack of response is due to an incoherent question.  Did you want to revise it?